# How do I move a Playlist from my iPod Nano to my computer using iTunes?

Tags: itunes, sync, ipod, playlists

I made a playlist and put it on my iPod Nano. However, when I was cleaning up the playlists on my computer (removing ones that I didn't play often, if ever), I accidentally deleted one of them that I wanted. The playlist is now only on my iPod.

Is there a way I can bring it back to my computer? I've already tried dragging the playlist from the iPod, but it doesn't work - I just get a circle with a line through it, signaling the operation is invalid.

If possible, I would prefer to do this using iTunes. If it can't be done, other tools would be acceptable.

Comment: You were using iTunes?

Comment: Yes, I was. The latest release, as well.

Comment: I just edited the title to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two free products to look at:

[SharePod](http://www.getsharepod.com/) : Does many things, among them

> Copy music, videos and playlists from
>   your iPod to PC

[YamiPod](http://www.yamipod.com/main/modules/home/) (Yet Another iPod Manager) also has many functions, among them:

> - playlist support (On-The-Go included)
> - playlists import (PLS,M3U)
> - playlists export (PLS,M3U)

Comment: Is there no way to do this task without another application? It seems like iTunes should be able to do this task.

Comment: No, iTunes won't do what you want. As always, iTunes only does what iTunes wants, and it does not want to "download" a playlist from your iPod to your computer (even if it formerly was on your PC). Additionally, if you have automatic synch activated, the playlist will be deleted from your iPod, too ... This is iTunes :)

Comment: Well, I guess I'm lucky I only manually sync...Thanks Martin and harrymc.